# Xamarin.TestUI Navigating repeating objects

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

Lets say I have a listview in a native app (not webapp). Each listview item has child labels with AutomationID 'name', 'date', and 'time' and a button with AutomationID 'info'.

In my test, I want to click on the info button for an item that has a specific date.

Coming from selenium, one way i'd find my button is to first find the listview item that has child 'date' with value "specificDate", then I'd find that listview items child 'info' button and click.

This is the ugly solution I'm using now:

```
x => x.Marked("VisitStartDate").All().Text(date)
            .Parent().Marked("VisitEntry").Descendant()
            .Marked("PatientName").Text(name)
            .Parent().Marked("VisitEntry").Descendant()
            .Marked("VisitInfo");
```

Id like to avoid all these repeating Parent() Descendant() calls.

In short I'm having trouble navigating repeatable elements without the structure selenium provides.

Comment: Repl is the way to go my friend. Could you provide some output from it, so we clearly see the structure you now describe. A image says more than 1000 words! (if you have the right image)

Comment: @PixelPlex any complex structure can navigated the same way in selenium with its provided tools. I'm asking if xamarin provides similar tools im missing.